# Why Mage::getBaseUrl is returning Admin Custom URL?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, ce-1.7.0.2, base-url

In Magento 1.7.0.2 I have a custom URL and path for admin.

The custom path it was set up in `local.xml`

```
<admin> <routers> <adminhtml> <args> <frontName>
```

And the custom URL on admin **System > Config > Advanced > Admin > Admin Base URL**

After that, the following lines are inserted in DB:

```
'1236','default','0','admin/url/custom','http://admin.mydomain.com/'
'1239','default','0','admin/url/use_custom_path','0'
'1240','stores','0','web/secure/base_url','https://admin.mydomain.com/'
'1241','stores','0','web/unsecure/base_url','http://admin.mydomain.com/'
```

When I use  `<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>` is returning base URL for links of custom admin (http://admin.mydomain.com/index.php/)

Because of this behavior, it puts URL admin in the cart and checkout.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Works fine here. Did you set up the base URLs for the default scope/frontend stores correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The DB changes that you listed set the `admin.mydomain.com` as the `secure` and `unsecure` `base_url`. When you are calling the `getBaseUrl` function it is simply returning these values. In order to fix this issue you need to update the `web/secure/base_url` and `web/unsecure/base_url` back to what they should be (I am assuming something like `www.mydomain.com`). These values should be in the core_config table of your database.